# ASP.net CORE 3.1 views are missing when publishing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I developped an ASP.net CORE 3.1 application. I recently bought a domain and published my project into a Windows shared host, so I do not have access to IIS.

When I launched my app, I get the following :

```
2020-06-22 23:02:21.411 +02:00 [INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2020-06-22 23:02:21.411 +02:00 [INF] Hosting environment: Production
2020-06-22 23:02:21.411 +02:00 [INF] Content root path: E:\kunden\homepages\24\d833115679\www\dev
2020-06-22 23:02:21.430 +02:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://dev.mywebsite.com/  
2020-06-22 23:02:21.486 +02:00 [INF] Authorization failed.
2020-06-22 23:02:21.490 +02:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: CookieAuthentication was challenged.
2020-06-22 23:02:21.501 +02:00 [INF] Request finished in 73.8851ms 302 
2020-06-22 23:02:22.852 +02:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://dev.mywebsite.com/EspaceProprietaire/Connexion?ReturnUrl=%2F  
2020-06-22 23:02:22.863 +02:00 [INF] Executing endpoint 'utpmv.api.Controllers.EspaceProprietaireController.Connexion (utpmv.api)'
2020-06-22 23:02:22.881 +02:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "Connexion", controller = "EspaceProprietaire"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Connexion() on controller utpmv.api.Controllers.EspaceProprietaireController (utpmv.api).
2020-06-22 23:02:22.897 +02:00 [INF] Executing ViewResult, running view Connexion.
2020-06-22 23:02:22.899 +02:00 [ERR] The view 'Connexion' was not found. Searched locations: ["/Views/EspaceProprietaire/Connexion.cshtml","/Views/Shared/Connexion.cshtml"]
2020-06-22 23:02:22.911 +02:00 [INF] Executed action utpmv.api.Controllers.EspaceProprietaireController.Connexion (utpmv.api) in 24.7936ms
2020-06-22 23:02:22.912 +02:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'utpmv.api.Controllers.EspaceProprietaireController.Connexion (utpmv.api)'
2020-06-22 23:02:22.914 +02:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Connexion' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/EspaceProprietaire/Connexion.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Connexion.cshtml
```

In the published folder, I do not have any views but I do have utpmv.api.Views.dll. I know in CORE 3.1 the views are precompilled so it makes sense the views are not there as cshtml files.

However, I tried to add them at the same level of all the other published files and I still get the same issue. The views are missing and/or the app cannot find them. Of course, my project works perfectly on local with IIS Express.

Here is my publish configuration:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\Release\publish\</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>a9405909-b7a5-4293-9103-67301e71a0b4</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I looked online and stackoverflow but I did not find an answer.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How did you publish? `dotnet publish`?

Comment: Hi, I published with Visual Studio. I added my publish profil in the description.

Comment: If possible, learn and use `dotnet publish`. You can then verify the generated artifacts locally before uploading to your remote server. Running on IIS Express successfully is never a valid proof, as VS runs your app completely different there, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Comment: Hi @Dorian,Please try to host on local IIS and check if it works well.And did your views in an area?

Comment: Hi Thank you for your suggestion. I was going to install Hosting bundle to debug it, but I gave a try at updating the Build Action of my views from None to Content. This action removed many lines in my csproj and now my project works fine.
However I do not know why I had to change this setting. I do not have any new dll or folder in my publish folder.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the Build Action of my views from None to Content. This action removed many lines in my csproj and now my project works fine.

However I do not know why I had to change this setting. I do not have any new dll or folder in my publish folder.

If someone can give us a clear explanation that would help understand why the default configuration does not allow the view to work.

Comment: I had the same issue, and cleaned up my csproj, muddied probably due to many include and exclude clicks. Then cleaned out obj and bin folders, then closed and reopened VS, and published... working, for now.